# Download hosted feature service that I don't own?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, arcgis-collector, desktop-gis

So I have access to a hosted feature service, and I want to take from ArcGIS online and download to use in ArcMap. I didn't create this feature service. I don't own it, so the options I would typically use aren't available to me. (i.e: there's no export option on the right side of the feature's services overview page, nor is there an option under the layer to download as a geodatabase. Click on 'Open in ArcGIS Desktop' just downloads an item.pitem (don't know what that is).

Is there a way for me to download this data without creating a replica?

Is there a way for me to sync edits from ArcMap back into ArcGIS online?

Comment: Have you considered contacting the author and asking permission?

Comment: Esri wrote a python tool for this. https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-6496-download-arcgis-online-feature-service-or-arcgis-server-featuremap-service

Comment: If you uses a feature service, then you are downloading the data when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can sync if you are not authorized
there are couple of ways I know to replicate/download the data, first open qgis and add the feature service or map service 
Once the data is loaded you can then right click the layer name and save as a shapefile or some other formats, 
If you do not have qGIS you can login/register to demo.cartoview.net you will find a tool that will copy the GIS feature service URL to a geonode layer, once the layer is created visit the layer page you will find a download link for a shape file and some other formats

Answer (score 0):

The hosted feature layer will need to be enabled for data sync, but this can only be done by the hosted layers publisher (ie: Not you).

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/enable-offline-mapping.htm

Also in the above link documentation, it suggests that having the author enable this, will also help facilitate downloading the data into ArcMap, ready for data sync back.

So - on the assumption that you are allowed to edit the data or its yours to edit, you will need to get in contact with an AGOL administrator that can facilitate this.